# How to load a html file into div tabs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created nav-tabs using bootstrap. Now I want to load html files into tab content on tab click. Can someone help me with java script.

This is my html:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
       <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" id="Home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a data-toggle="pill" id="Menu1" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
       <li><a data-toggle="pill" id="Menu2" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active"> 
         </div>
         <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
         </div>
         <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade"> <h3>Menu 2</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

In the above code, when i click on the home tab i want to load an external html(x.html) file into home div under tab-content div. I want the same functionality when i click on the menu1 tab(y.html). When I load (y.html) i need to hide (x.html).  Someone please help me...!!!

I used the below javascript. But it is not working.:

```
$('a#Home').click(function(){
    $("#home").load("x.html");
});
$('a#Menu1').click(function(){
   $("#menu1").load("y.html");
});
```

Comment: Why are you using different DIVs for the content, just use a single DIV that you load the desired content into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hide()`, `.show()`

```
$('a#Home').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#home").load("x.html", function() {
      $("#menu1").hide();
      $(this).show();
    });        
});

$('a#Menu1').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#menu1").load("y.html", function() {
     $("#home").hide();
     $(this).show();
   })       
});
```

Comment: It is loading the html files. But i have used same contents in both html files which I'm loading. It is blocking some functionality.

Comment: _"It is blocking some functionality"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: In the x.html file i can navigate through cpp,java tabs. The y.html also has same tabs with same names cpp,java. But it is not navigating. My doubt is since those are two different html files it should work independently even though with same tab names.

Comment: What is "cpp,java tabs"? Can you reproduce issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co?